# How do I disable form dropdown option using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to disable the "name" text field in the form when "Choose" is selected in the drop down *after* the page loads (it's disabled when the page loads) ie after I've chosen one of the other two options that disable or enable that field, when I return to "Choose" i'd like the same field to disable. I can't see why the javascript I've written would prevent this from happening. Thanks!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function clickclear(thisfield, defaulttext) {
        if (thisfield.value === defaulttext) {
            thisfield.value = "";
        }
    }

    function clickrecall(thisfield, defaulttext) {
        if (thisfield.value === "") {
            thisfield.value = defaulttext;
        }
    }

    function checkPickup() {

        if (form.os0.value != "Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane" ) {
            form.name.disabled = false; form.name.style.color = '#333';

        } else {

            form.name.disabled = true; form.name.style.color = '#CCC';
            /* Reset form values */
            form.name.value = "His/her name";
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(form) {

        var errmsg = "Oops, you're required to complete the following fields! \n";

        // Various other form validations here

        // Validate "Pickup"
        if (form.os0.value === "") {
            errmsg = errmsg + " - Choose pickup or delivery\n";
        }

        // Validate "phone"
        if (form.phone.value === "" || form.phone.value === "Mobile's best!") {
            errmsg = errmsg + " - Your phone number\n";
        }


        if (form.os0.value != "Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane") {

            // Validate "name"
            if (form.name.value === "" || form.name.value === "His/her name") {
                errmsg = errmsg + " - His/her name\n";
            }
        }

        // Alert if fields are empty and cancel form submit
        if (errmsg === "Oops, you're required to complete the following fields! \n") {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            alert(errmsg);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onSubmit="return validate(form)">

            <p class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Pickup and delivery" />Pickup and delivery<br />
                <select name="os0" onchange="checkPickup()">
                    <option value="" selected >Choose</option>
                    <option value="Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane">Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane $1.00 AUD</option>
                    <option value="Brisbane +$23.60">Brisbane +$23.60 =$1.00 AUD</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="row">Your daytime phone number<br />
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="Mobile's best!" onclick="clickclear(this, 'Mobile\'s best!')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Mobile\'s best!')" />
            </p>
            <p class="row">Recipient's name<br />
                <input style="color: #ccc" class="name" type="text" name="name" value="His/her name" onclick="clickclear(this, 'His/her name')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'His/her name')" disabled />
            </p>
            <input name="custom" type="hidden"  />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />
            <input class="button" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." />
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As there are other options that need enabling when "Choose" or "Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane" aren't selected (sorry, was trying to keep post short), then I've flipped the function at http://jsfiddle.net/AWjKD/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This may be a simple misunderstanding of what you've written:**

```
if (form.os0.value != "Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane" ) {
    form.name.disabled = false; form.name.style.color = '#333';
} else {
    form.name.disabled = true; form.name.style.color = '#CCC';
    //
}
```

translates to the following in plain english:

> If the value is *NOT* `"Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane"`, enable the field, otherwise disable it.

which is equivalent to:

> *ONLY* disable the field when the value is `"Pickup from Toowong, Brisbane"`.

**I believe the logic you're looking for is:**

```
if (form.os0.value == "Brisbane +$23.60" ) {
    form.name.disabled = false; form.name.style.color = '#333';
} else {
    form.name.disabled = true; form.name.style.color = '#CCC';
    //
}
```

though it might be prettier to code this with a `switch` statement due to the involvement of specific cases.

- See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fWRyG/)**

Comment: Thanks! I can see where you're coming from but as I simplified the form for the purpose of this post, sorry, you wouldn't have been aware of a list of select values to choose from similar to "Brisbane +$23.60". Got it working at http://jsfiddle.net/AWjKD/2

Answer (score 0):

did you intend to type double equal to (==) or is the triple equal to (===) a typo in the question? Based on looking at your code, it looks to me like you need a double equal to (==) not a triple. I think triple may mean something else.

Comment: consider changing this to a comment. even if `===` was used incorrectly, its not even in the code that has to do with the question

Comment: i am seeing that the code has === throughout all the functions in the if conditions. So it could be an answer.

Comment: Code Academy recommend === over ==. Apparently there are issues with using == in some browsers.